# Console command to give each player an AK47 on a custom map's round start

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

We are trying to 1v1 using only AK in CS:GO.

How do you use the developer console to start each player with an AK47 no matter what side they are on?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to be in a private server where you can turn `sv_cheats 1` on. If you are playing on a server where you can't do that, you will need to try and get the `rcon_password` for that server and execute `sv_cheats 1`.

Once you have done that, best practice is executing the script I linked below, copy paste that into a `grens.cfg` file and place it in your `csgo/cfg` directory.

```
bot_kick
mp_respawn_on_death_t 1
mp_respawn_on_death_ct 1
sv_cheats 1
sv_infinite_ammo 1
sv_grenade_trajectory 1
sv_grenade_trajectory_time 5
sv_showimpacts 1
sv_showimpacts_time 5
mp_buytime 99999
mp_buy_anywhere 1
mp_roundtime 99999
mp_roundtime_defuse 99999
mp_roundtime_hostage 99999
mp_limitteams 0
mp_autoteambalance 0
mp_solid_teammates 1
mp_freezetime 2
mp_startmoney 16000
ammo_grenade_limit_total 6
mp_spectators_max" = "10" 
mp_restartgame 1
god
```

Now load up your map, type in `exec grens.cfg`. Now you can type `buy ak47` in console and anybody should be able to get an AK47 on CT and T.